# Can I add colorpicker in django-models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hello is it possible to add a color picker in a django model?

I need to have a color in my model so it can be passed to the front-end in `Hex Color Code`

I can do that with saving the hex color In char field, but is it possible to have an actual color-picker in Django admin

Comment: The "interface" is not really part of the models layer, but of the forms layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how good is this. You can try this third party [django-colorfield](https://github.com/jaredly/django-colorfield).